# Loop through a list in Python using enumerate and openpyxl

Tags: python, loops, enums, openpyxl

New Python convert here. Simply, trying to loop through a list in Python using openpyxl. Of course, my list has about 100 items and my code has more conditions.

```
lst = ['1','2','a','a12']

for value in enumerate(lst):
    row = ws1.iter_rows(min_row=value,max_row=value)
```

When I try without `enumerate` I get error "must be str, not int" and when I try with `enumerate` I get error "Can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple".

I believe it has something to do with `min_row` and `max_row` requiring an `int`, but even then I get "'int' object is not iterable". Also, tried making value `str()` and `int()`

Any advice much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Tip: don't combine `enumerate` with `ws.iter_rows()` you almost certainly don't need to. `zip(lst, rows)` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you wrap an iterable with `enumerate`, you get two values:

- the index of enumeration
- the value of the iterable at that index

That pair is emitted from `enumerate()` as a tuple.
You're only identifying one variable name, though, so `value` contains the whole tuple,
i.e. `value = (i, current_val_of_lst)`.

Instead, try:

```
lst = ['1','2','a','a12']

for i, value in enumerate(lst):
    # i is the enumeration index
    # value is the entry in list
    ...
```

Comment: Perfect, I replace 'value' with 'i' for 'min_row' and 'max_row'

Comment: Yes.  But if all you want is `i`, just use `for i in range(len(lst)): ...`